# Create vue component in twig loop

Tags: vue.js, twig, vue-component

I am learning Vue for a symfony project and I have run into a problem.

I need to create some cards from an array. I have created a card component and am trying to call them in a loop, but it only creates one element. Can someone guide me?

This is ny code:

game-card.js:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Gamecard from './../components/Gamecard'
    
new Vue({
    render(h) {
        return h(Gamecard);
    }
}).$mount('#game-card')
```

Gamecard.vue

```html
<template>
...
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    name: 'gamecard',
    props: ['card-id'],
    data() {
      return {
    
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

twig where I call component in loop

```html
<div id="game-card"></div>
{% for game in games %}
    <gamecard card-id="card-{{ game.getId() }}"/>
{% endfor %}
```

Array games have 6 elements, but only one is rendered.

Thank you

Comment: `<gamecard v-for="game in games" card-id="card-{{ game.id }}"/>`

Comment: do looping in vue not twig